# Add column and button to inbox to mark emails as read/unread?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Sorry if this question is vague.  In Thunderbird and the Yahoo Mail web interface, there are small circular icons.  When you click those items, it will toggle the item as read/unread.    What I was hoping to do is create or find an add-on to reproduce this.

[image: notice the green circle button]

Notice that green circle button with the "eyeglasses" above it?  Clicking that will toggle read/unread.  It's very useful when you get many automated emails over night because you can click, click, click.

Are such add-ons possible in the list of emails?   Thanks in advance for any advice.   I'd also like to take another idea from Yahoo Mail, where they have in-line delete buttons.[image: notice the garbage can icon]

Notice the garbage can icon on the grey row where the subject begins with "ghacks"?  You don't even have to click into an item to delete it.  Again, very useful for automated emails or spam.

I realize I can hit CTRL+click (or SHIFT+click) to select multiple items and then perform a task, however I've gotten very used to the Thunderbird and Yahoo Mail style of interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2013 introduced a vertical selector to the left of the email in the folder list that you can toggle the read/unread state with:

[image]

But there is nothing you can do to provide a custom UI like you are looking for within the grid or columns directly. That entire list is locked down for customizations aside from what you can modify from the View settings (or from a custom right-click context menu).  Otherwise any custom message list UIs require it to be written completely from scratch via a custom web folder view such as you can implement with Add-in Express' Web View Regions.  But that effort is not for the faint of heart as there would be a LOT of functionality you'd have to recreate!